# Creating new Xcode project from an existing Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one app with some app name in the App Store, is it possible to create a different app from the same project in the Xcode by changing the info plist values like bundle id ,bundle name etc with out creating a new project.And can i upload the same to the App Store with a different app name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a second 'target' inside your existing XCode project.

There are a number of different target types you can create, one of them being another application.

This new application target then needs a different bundle id etc. However that target can see all the existing code you wrote for your existing app so you don't need to copy the files into another project to reuse them.  Use the search facility in Apple dev website, or Google the use of XCode targets for more information about how to do this.